# Generating an add() function to a system created with a Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, addition

I'm trying to make a phone book using Linked List.

I get the following error when I start printList function  after adding new data with the add() function.

AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'data'.

My printList function works before I add() something .

```
class Record:

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number


class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


r1 = Record(name="selman", number="541")
r2 = Record(name="mustafa", number="542")
r3 = Record(name="fatih", number="543")
r1_node = Node(data=r1)
r2_node = Node(data=r2)
r3_node = Node(data=r3)
phone_book = LinkedList()
phone_book.head = r1_node
r1_node.next = r2_node
r2_node.next = r3_node


def printList():
    temp = phone_book.head
    while temp:
        print(f"name: {temp.data.name} ---> number: {temp.data.number}")
        temp = temp.next


def add(name, number):
    r_new = Record(name, number)
    new_node = Node(data=r_new)
    new_node.next = phone_book
    phone_book.head = new_node


printList()
add("ahmet", "544")
printList()
```

Comment: rather than `new_node.next = phone_book` try `new_node.next = phone_book.head`

Comment: This should be a `LinkedList` method rather than a function.

Answer (score 1):

rather than new_node.next = phone_book try new_node.next = phone_book.head

[Thank you for answer JonSG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218663/jonsg)

```
class Record:

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number


class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


r1 = Record(name="selman", number="541")
r2 = Record(name="mustafa", number="542")
r3 = Record(name="fatih", number="543")
r1_node = Node(data=r1)
r2_node = Node(data=r2)
r3_node = Node(data=r3)
phone_book = LinkedList()
phone_book.head = r1_node
r1_node.next = r2_node
r2_node.next = r3_node


def printList():
    temp = phone_book.head
    while temp:
        print(f"name: {temp.data.name} ---> number: {temp.data.number}")
        temp = temp.next


def add(name, number):
    r_new = Record(name, number)
    new_node = Node(data=r_new)
    new_node.next = phone_book.head
    phone_book.head = new_node



add("ahmet", "544")
printList()
```